# Read barcode from an uploaded image in java

Tags: java, barcode, barcode-scanner

I've to read barcode from an uploaded image file for a java based web application. I've tried Zxing and other similar libraries, but it will work only if we upload precise images. Could anyone suggest an api for reading barcode from an image? The image could be a randomly clicked one and it might contain other data also. From that, we have to identify the barcode and decode it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

As you did not provide a whole lot of information I will try to help you out with what I think what the problem is.

I think ZXing should be the right way to go. The barcode decoder searches for the barcode within an image per default. If you have an image wich only contains the barcode itself you can set the hint *PURE_BARCODE* to speed up decoding. There only could be problems if you have multiple barcodes within a single image.

Your problem seems to be the uploaded image not ZXing. I would suggest checking whether the image is uploaded correctly.

Here is an example of decoding a BufferedImage with any ZXing reader.

```
public void decodeCode() throws IOException, NotFoundException, FormatException, ChecksumException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(yourImage);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = convertImageToBinaryBitmap(image);
    Result result = reader.decode(bitmap, hints);

    assertNotNull("DecoderResult must not be null", result);
    System.out.println(result.getText());
  }

 protected BinaryBitmap convertImageToBinaryBitmap(BufferedImage image) {
    int[] pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0,
                                image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                                null, 0, image.getWidth());
    RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(image.getWidth(),
                                                       image.getHeight(),
                                                       pixels);
    return new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
  }
```